# Error Code: 1648. Data too long for condition item 'MESSAGE_TEXT'

Tags: mysql, triggers, compiler-errors, mysql-workbench

This is my trigger, i've declared **msg varchar(255)** and **i've tried to change it from 255 to  550**  but it doesn't stop to send me that error code:

***Error Code: 1648. Data too long for condition item 'MESSAGE_TEXT***

**The msg variable is declared in a trigger**; the trigger is a merge of 2 triggers (i'm working by MySQL and i can't use multiple triggers for the same action time and event on one table) **and this is the body:**

```
-- --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
CREATE TRIGGER BEFORE_INSERT_ON_SENTIERO__HA__TAPPA
BEFORE INSERT ON SENTIERO__HA__TAPPA
FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN

/* TRIGGER controlla_MaxCARDINALITA_INSERT */

-- variables for controlla_MaxCARDINALITA_INSERT
DECLARE max_cardinalita INTEGER;
DECLARE msg varchar(255);

-- variables for controlla_corrispondenzaTappaFineInizio_INSERT
DECLARE temp_tappaOLD INTEGER;
DECLARE temp_posizione_tappaOLD INTEGER;
DECLARE temp_inizio_tappaNEW VARCHAR(45);
DECLARE temp_fine_tappaOLD VARCHAR(45);


SELECT COUNT(*) into max_cardinalita
FROM SENTIERO__HA__TAPPA
WHERE IDsentiero=NEW.IDsentiero;

IF max_cardinalita>=10 THEN

        set msg = 'INSERT: Il sentiero ha già il massimo numero di tappe consentito ';
        signal sqlstate '45000' set message_text = msg;

END IF;



/* TRIGGER controlla_corrispondenzaTappaFineInizio_INSERT */

IF EXISTS ( SELECT IDsentiero, IDtappa
            FROM SENTIERO__HA__TAPPA as sht
            WHERE NEW.IDsentiero=sht.IDsentiero and NEW.IDtappa=sht.IDtappa) THEN

            set msg = 'INSERT: La tappa inserita è già presente nel sentiero; non è possibile inserirla 2 volte ';
            signal sqlstate '45000' set message_text = msg;

END IF;

SELECT IDtappa into temp_tappaOLD
FROM SENTIERO__HA__TAPPA as sht1
WHERE NEW.IDsentiero=sht1.IDsentiero and posizione_tappa>=ALL ( SELECT posizione_tappa
                                                                FROM SENTIERO__HA__TAPPA as sht2
                                                                WHERE NEW.IDsentiero=sht2.IDsentiero );

SELECT posizione_tappa into temp_posizione_tappaOLD
FROM SENTIERO__HA__TAPPA as sht
WHERE NEW.IDsentiero=sht.IDsentiero and temp_tappaOLD=sht.IDtappa;

IF NEW.posizione_tappa<>temp_posizione_tappaOLD THEN

        set msg = 'INSERT: La posizione della tappa inserita deve essere consecutiva alla posizione dell ultima tappa di quel sentiero: le tappe devono essere consecutive ';
        signal sqlstate '45000' set message_text = msg;

END IF;

SELECT inizio into temp_inizio_tappaNEW
FROM TAPPA
WHERE NEW.IDtappa=TAPPA.IDtappa;

SELECT fine into temp_fine_tappaOLD
FROM TAPPA
WHERE temp_tappaOLD=TAPPA.IDtappa;

IF temp_inizio_tappaNEW<>temp_fine_tappaOLD THEN

        set msg = 'INSERT: La fine della tappa precedente non corrisponde con l inizio di questa tappa: le tappe devono essere consecutive ';
        signal sqlstate '45000' set message_text = msg;

END IF;


END$$
-- --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

**EDIT ::**

```
DECLARE msg varchar(5);
set msg = concat('I');
signal sqlstate '45000' set message_text = msg;
```

Comment: the reason is that you are inserting a text that is beyond the maximum amount allocated for the column `MESSAGE_TEXT`. eg, the max length is 50, but you are inserting value greater than 50.

Comment: ook so the size of **MESSAGE_TEXT** isn't checked until that variable won't be used, is it correct? Beacuse i've the same  variable type,size,and name in another trigger, but i didn't got no **Error-Code raised with SIGNAL** from it

Comment: **ANYWAY** if i change ***msg VARCHAR(255)*** to ***msg VARCHAR(50)*** and ***set msg = concat('INSERT ')*** , it **DOESN'T WORK** !

Comment: how long are the strings you have concatenated?

Comment: how about change it into `DECLARE msg varchar(MAX);` does it throws any error?

Comment: **MAX** doesn't work, syntax error; **BUT** if i change **('INSERT: ..... ')** into **('INSERT: ')** it works; i've deleted just only 50 characters i think, and triyng to set a bigger size (from 255 to 500) for variable **msg** it doesn't work......... but the problem is still alive, it's not useful an error-code **INSERT**

Answer (score 10):

`MESSAGE_TEXT` is, in MySQL, `VARCHAR(128)`. Some of your messages, you are trying to assign there, are longer than that.

I guess one can not simply redefine MESSAGE_TEXT so you have to come up with a shorter message. See
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/signal.html#signal-condition-information-items.

Answer (score 3):

I think you can't modify the definition of the condition item (see [this](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/signal.html)). The definition for `MESSAGE_TEXT` is `VARCHAR(128)`; I tried to change this, but couldn't.

But, you can use MariaDB (works like MySQL). In MariaDB the condition item `MESSAGE_TEXT` has the definition `VARCHAR(512)`. So, you can't change this, but it can contain more now. [This](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/diagnostics-area/) works only for MariaDB in version 10.3.6 an up.